# Can't call function inside another function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

M question is why the `Cal_Total_Amount()` function doesn't work in the `add_row()` function when I try to add new row.
The function `Cal_Total_Amount()` works only on the main row table.

```
 function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length - 1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
    var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);

    cell1.innerHTML = '<label style="width:100%" type="text" id="Total_Amount" class="form-control" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off"  onclick="Cal_Total_Amount(this);" ></label>';
    cell2.innerHTML = '<label style="width:100%" type="text" id="VAT_amount"   class="form-control" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off"  onclick="Cal_Total_Amount(this);" ></label>';
    cell3.innerHTML = '<input style="width:100%" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off" />';
    cell4.innerHTML = '<input style="width:100%" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off" />';
    cell5.innerHTML = '<input style="width:100%" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off" />';
    cell6.innerHTML = '<input style="width:100%" type="month" class="form-control" name="start" min="2021-10" value="2021-10">';
    cell7.innerHTML = '<input style="width:100%" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off" />';
    cell8.innerHTML = '<input style="width:100%" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off" />';
    cell9.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn_delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="bx bx-trash"></i></button>';
}


function Cal_Total_Amount() {
    var Tp = +document.getElementById("Total_Price").value;
    var v = +document.getElementById("VAT").value;
    var VATmont = (Tp * v) / 100;
    var Total = VATmont + Tp;
    document.getElementById("Total_Amount").innerHTML = Total;
    document.getElementById("VAT_amount").innerHTML = VATmont;
}
```

Comment: Why is there a plus sign in front of "document.getElementById("Total_Price").value" in Cal_Total_Amount? Is it a asp.net thing?

Comment: @SatbirKira it's the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator and it is used to convert the string value to a number type